# QBO v2 API Invoice query goes boom

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

peeps! I'm attempting to load an invoice from Quickbooks online using v2 of the Java API with  the following code:

```
    public String getInvoiceFoo(String docNumber, PlatformSessionContext context) throws QBInvalidContextException, Exception {
    QBInvoiceQuery query = new QBInvoiceQuery(context);
    query.setDocNumber(docNumber);
    QBInvoiceService invoiceService = QBServiceFactory.getService(context, QBInvoiceService.class);
    QBInvoice qbInvoice = invoiceService.getInvoices(context, query).get(0);
    return qbInvoice.getHeader().getDocNumber();
}
```

This seemingly simple query results in the following error:

```
Error: 400 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><FaultInfo xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/baseexceptionmodel/xsd"><Message>Search Criteria has invalid PropertyName: DocNumber</Message><ErrorCode>BAD_QUERY_REQUEST</ErrorCode><Cause>QUERY_INVALID_SEARCH_CRITERIA</Cause></FaultInfo>
```

The server seems to complain about DocNumber being an invalid property. Has anyone else successfully queried invoices by number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering by docnumber is not supported for Invoices in V2 QBO.
Please refer:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_deprecated/qbo_v2/0400_qbo_v2_reference/invoice

Please use V3 services for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That said, it blows my mind that you cannot do a lookup by the only natural key over invoices.

Answer (score 1):

I too got the same problem while using V2 Invoice.

I tried this    `Filter= DocNumber :EQUALS: f96fa`

Filter support only provided for Estimate entity.

V2 will be deprecated. If possible, try this using V3. It is working fine.

```
    Invoice invoice = GenerateQuery.createQueryEntity(Invoice.class);
    String invoiceQuery = select($(invoice)).where($(invoice.getDocNumber()).eq("f96fa")).generate();
    //SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE DocNumber = 'f96fa'
    this.service.executeQuery(invoiceQuery);
```

Thanks